# OpenCV set FPS to camera not working

Tags: c++, opencv, camera

I am currently doing real-time face evaluation and is trying to set the FPS of the Camera of my computer to 1 frame per second, followed by calling the cascade functions only once per second. (Currently using a While(true) loop) This is due to the limitation of my GPU.

I have tried to set the FPS of the camera by using

```
VideoCapture cap(0); 
cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS, 1);
namedWindow("webcam",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
```

but it is not working. The camera still process at a relative high FPS.

For the cascade function calling, I am doing it as below:

```
while ( true ){

        cap >> frame;
        vector<Rect> faces;
        face_cascade.detectMultiScale( frame, faces, 1.1, 2, 0|CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(30, 30) );

        // Draw circles on the detected faces
        for( int i = 0; i < faces.size(); i++ )
        {
            Point center( faces[i].x + faces[i].width*0.5, faces[i].y + faces[i].height*0.5 );
            cout<<"Face location: "<<faces[i].x<<","<<faces[i].x + faces[i].width<<","<<faces[i].y<<","<<faces[i].y + faces[i].height;
            ellipse( frame, center, Size( faces[i].width*0.5, faces[i].height*0.5), 0, 0, 360, Scalar( 255, 0, 255 ), 4, 8, 0 );
        }

        waitKey(30);  
       if ( !frame.data ){ 
            cerr << "Cannot acquire frame from the webcam " << endl;
            break;
       } 
       imshow("webcam", frame); 
    }
```

I need the camera to go for only 1 frame per second, followed by calling the cascade functions once per second.

Edit: I have tried to display the FPS of the camera by using

```
        int FPS = cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS);
```

It did show that FPS is currently at 1, but it seems that the camera is still moving at a relative high frame rate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the frame rate does not always work. Sometimes the camera simply does not respond to this change. However, you can do something to solve your problem in a tricky way. Measure the time that it takes to processing a frame then subtract it from 1000 mSec (1000 - Elapsce_Time) and make it wait for this time `cv::waitKey(1000-Elapsce_Time)`. Finally, this is not a very way to do it. You should search for the actual problem with the camera and try to solve it.

Comment: Thanks! WaitKey did worked for me! I have tried the other method, by calling a C++ "Sleep" function in the loop which works as well but I believe it is not really efficient. I could not determine the problem with the camera (most probably due to my computer).

Comment: cv::waitKey Must work. otherwise, you have something wrong in your code or in linking to OpenCV or something else I do know.